# How to access an element by giving a variable in JSP using getElementById?

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have the following code:

```
var id1="Times"+another_variable;
alert(document.getElementById(id1).className);
```

Basically, I need to pass a variable in the getElementById, how do i do it?

Comment: What's wrong with the code in your question?  Looks just fine to me

Comment: not sure what you mean by pass a variable.

Comment: When I do alert(id1); it works fine. But doing the getElementById, it does not work. Any ideas???

Comment: @SarthakSahu do you have an element in the DOM with that id?

Comment: @kjy112 Yes, I do have an element with exactly that id!!!

Comment: @SarthakSahu should work. include your html. check case sensitivity

Comment: @SarthakSahu here is a jsfiddle that simulates what you have http://jsfiddle.net/kjy112/8uYKM/

Comment: you're alerting the className, so if it doesn't have one it might not be a very interesting alert. are you sure you have an element by that id AND it has a class attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing a small mistake with the id name. It was not able to find the Id of the element. Once I corrected the id variable, it started working!

Sorry guys, for bothering!!!