# getElementByID using a Variable

Tags: javascript, variables, getelementbyid

I am trying to make multiple text input fields share a value. The text fields are named StartDate#, where # is replaced with a number. I am trying to use the following code:

```
function SetTimeFrame(element) {
    if (document.Labs.SameDate.checked==true) {
        var Elements=document.Labs.elements.length;
        for (var i=0; i<Elements; i++) {
            if (document.Labs.elements[i].type=='select-one') {
                    document.Labs.elements[i].options[element.selectedIndex].selected=true;
                    document.getElementById("StartDate"+i).value = document.getElementById("StartDate0").value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I use this code I receive the following error:

> Javascript error at position (45:7): 'document.getElementById[...]' is null or not an object

45:7 is the line:

```
document.getElementById("StartDate"+i).value = document.getElementById("StartDate0").value;
```

It appears that it isn't appending the value of "i" to "StartDate" as it iterates through the forloop. I know that I have "StartDate0" and "StartDate1" in the page, so I know they are not null.

I looked at a couple of other Stack Overflow questions similar to mine such as, [getElementById with a variable plus an id name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10833826/getelementbyid-with-a-variable-plus-an-id-name), and [How to access an element by giving a variable in JSP using getElementById?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5184779/how-to-access-an-element-by-giving-a-variable-in-jsp-using-getelementbyid) but neither prooved to give a sucessful solution.

Any help given would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a jsFiddle? - http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: Are you sure you are iterating through the correct number of elements? What is the value of `document.Labs.elements.length` Does it match the number of `StartDate#` inputs you have?

Comment: What happens when you hard-code the value? For example, `document.getElementById("StartDate1")...`

Comment: @palintropos When I hardcode in "StartDate1" the value is copied from "StartDate0" to "StartDate1" as expected.

Comment: Add a console.log statement to the loop and have it log something like "StartDate"+i. Perhaps you are simply going one index too far as suggested above?

Comment: Post your HTML or a jsFiddle please.